# Zebra PDF Printing from Android

Tags: android, pdf, printing, zebra-printers

I have a web application that produces PDF printing. We have dozens of Android apps that we use for various reasons, mainly inventory.

I bought a couple QLN220 and QLN420 devices, but am having a very hard time trying to print our barcode labels from PDF or from that application. Since the application is web based, I just us something like chrome, or mozilla to run the application. 
Everything works exceptional a windows platform, but trying to print from Android to Zebra from a PDF and keep format has been difficult. I've tried Google Print, but just for some reason will not keep formatting. I works fine if I have the mobile printer plugged into a windows machine, but not if it's running off the Android device.

What are my options here? How are other people handling PDF barcode printing from Android Scanner to Zebra QLN Printers?

Answer (score 1):

now it is free with Link-OS 6.3, see the blog below
https://developer.zebra.com/blog/announcement-printers-include-free-pdf-direct-link-os-63

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to purchase a PDF virtual device and load it on the printer. More information here:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/pdf-virtual-device.html

Comment: You actually have tried this have you? We have a compatible device and our barcodes are .pdf, but the android middle ware is junk and has a lot of issues. Hence the posting of we have QLN printers.

Comment: Yes, it acts as an add on to the printer firmware, so you can send straight pdfs with no fuss. The only downside is you have to buy a different virtual device for each printer youre using. Are you using the Link OS SDK to do the connection?

Comment: @person Hi I am using Link OS SDK and my printer is Zebra QLn420, Do I have to purchase PDF virtual device cause there is not any solution I could find, please let me know how it helps to implement in my personal app for printing PDF

Comment: hi all, I am also looking for the same. I want to use Link OS SDK and print PDFs directly without purchasing PDF virtual device add-on.